# Is there any difference between relative motion and motion itself

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

If relative motion is the change in position of a body with reference to another body,  and motion is the change in position of a body with time . Then why is relative motion not associated with the types of motion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object which is in motion is actually in relative motion. Suppose, you found an object which is in motion but not in relative motion. Ask yourself how do you know that the object is in motion? You will realize that the object is in motion with respect to you, which means the object is in relative motion.

I am not sure if you got the concept correctly or you did not frame your doubt properly. You seem to be confused with relative motion with motion.

Motion, as you said, is change in position with respect to time but the definition of relative motion you gave is not really correct. Relative motion is the change in position with respect to a point in space with time. In fact, relative motion and motion are exactly one and the same.

Any time you talk about motion , its relative motion. You say something is in motion because it is moving with respect to you which means, say what, it is in relative motion with respect to you.

There is no such thing as absolute motion.

Comment: So can we say that motion is by definition relative?

Comment: Yes, motion is by definition relative motion. They are identical and you can think of motion as a shorthand for relative motion.

Answer (score 0):

For everyday use, we say "motion" or "absolute motion" for the one that is relative to Earth surface. As soon as you go very high or very fast (relatively to Earth surface), Earth surface as a reference frame is not of much use. 
Consider a child with a toy with moving particles in a pool on some big tourist ship. "Absolute" motion of toy parts can be measured against the toy; toy to child hand, hand to child, child to pool water; pool water to ship, ship to ocean, ocean to a point on the land. No "absolute" so far.